# Rails Mongoid / MongoHD / Heroku error "need to login" when saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid

I have an error that appears to be connected to these two links:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongoid/L6ESKP8QDpg/gmEyqejdAEEJ
- https://github.com/mongoid/moped/pull/59

See console log below. I am running with Mongoid/MongoHQ, when I create an object (apparently any database object) I get this "need to login" error. Note however that the database object IS created and is in the database after the error.

Is there some way I can fix this myself, or perhaps it's something that MongoHQ needs to fix?

```
$ heroku run console
irb(main):004:0> Request.create!(:from_user => User.first, :to_user => User.first)
Moped::Errors::OperationFailure: The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=69
  @request_id=7
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="admin.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:getlasterror=>1, :safe=>true}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error "need to login"
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:74:in `block in command'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:521:in `[]'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:521:in `block (3 levels) in flush'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:520:in `map'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:520:in `block (2 levels) in flush'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:123:in `ensure_connected'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:516:in `block in flush'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:531:in `logging'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:515:in `flush'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:286:in `pipeline'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/session/context.rb:58:in `block in insert'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/session/context.rb:109:in `block in with_node'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/cluster.rb:150:in `block in with_primary'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/node.rb:168:in `ensure_primary'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/cluster.rb:149:in `with_primary'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/moped-1.2.0/lib/moped/session/context.rb:108:in `with_node'
... 13 levels...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:100:in `run_callbacks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:23:in `prepare'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:26:in `persist'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:50:in `insert'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:251:in `block in create!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:173:in `_creating'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.4/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:249:in `create!'
    from (irb):4
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that MongoHQ upgraded their MongoDB and it introduced an incompatibility with mongoid's stable branch.

[Chris Winslett fixed the bug and durran pulled it into mongoid master](https://github.com/mongoid/moped/commit/5e3ccde7d535785df2dcd955f1a5be552b43cb7c). But it was not included in the stable branch when I posted this stackoverflow.

Solutions:

- I solved the problem by updating my gemfile to pull mongoid from github.
- durran has now included it in stable-1.2.0 so you should get the fix if you `gem update`.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the exact same problem. This is not exactly a solution but you can work around the problem by setting the 'safe' option in mongoid.yml to false. It would look similar to this:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: false
```